# How do I get the main camera from a root object?

Tags: unity, c#

In my scene, all objects are children of game object named "SceneRoot".

The main camera is a child somewhere in this hierarchy, for example at

```
SceneRoot->Hero->Model->MainCamera;
```

I need to attach a raw image to it using code.

To do that, I first need to find this camera.

I have tried

```
GameObject go = SceneRoot.GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>();
```

But that throws the error

```
Type "UnityEngine.Camera[]" can't be converted to "UnityEngine.Camera".
```

How could I get the camera object in order to attach a raw image to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `GetComponentInChildren`, without the "s"?

When you use the plural, you're saying "give me ALL the cameras you find," so it has to return an array `Camera[]` to hold potentially multiple cameras.

When you use the singular, you're saying "give me the FIRST camera you find," so it's able to return either a single valid `Camera` or `null` if it can't find any.

Your compiler error describes this exact problem, so please be sure to read these messages carefully and investigate what they're telling you.